# Adapter and Adaptee Classes

Tags: c++, oop, adapter

I have an assignment where I am to create a class called HashTable that is to eventually store pairs of usernames and passwords and then another class called PassServer. The h file I am showing below are given and can be added to but not removed. To keep save space, here is what is pertinent to this question from HashTable:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
    class HashTable {
    public:
    .
    .
    .
    private:
       std::vector<std::list<std::pair<K, V>>> hashTable;
```

As for PassServer, we are only given a list of public and private functions we need to implement, no pre-defined h file. The only private data member required of PassServer is `string encrypt(const string & str);`.

Now, in the assignment it says:

"PassServer should be implemented as an adaptor class, with the HashTable
you developed as the adaptee class. The type for both K and V in HashTable
should be string. The key and value will be the username and password,
respectively."

I have never heard of an adapter and adaptee class until today so I am not sure what is the correct or best way to implement it. I have 3 different routes I am thinking.

1. I define PassServer to inherit HashTable: `class PassServer: public HashTable<string, string>`
2. `class PassServer: private HashTable<string, string>`
3. I don't inherit HashTable at all and instead add a private data member to PassServer like: `HashTable<string, string> passServer;`

I hope I provided enough information. This is an assignment so I don't want to post it all on here. I really just need to know about this because I don't know which is best(or right) and my professor can take a *very* long time to respond to questions and I am working on it now.

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of "adapter/adaptee classes" either. Perhaps he means a wrapper class? In that case it's number 3 in your list. That's what I would do in a real world scenario - inheritance doesn't seem the right fit for this. But, you know - professors sometimes have weird ideas...

Comment: @Vilx- What exactly constitutes a wrapper class and when it is most appropriate to use one?

Comment: I assume he's talking about the adapter pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern A search for that will probably give you more information than you really need, but my understanding is it's basically a wrapper.

Comment: What people normally understand as "wrappers" is when you take one class (A) and "wrap it around" another class (B) in order to provide a more suitable interface. B becomes a private member in A and you can't interact with it directly, but the methods in A allow you to do all that is needed. For example, you could make a "read-only" wrapper by only including those methods in A that don't change anything in B. They would be named the same and have the same parameters and all they would do is to call the corresponding method in B.

Comment: In your case `PassServer` would have a private member of `HashTable<string, string>` and its methods would be things like `addUser()`, `doesUserExist()`, `removeUser()`, `setPassword()`, etc. And when you call them, they would read/write the underlying `HashTable`, with some extra steps as needed (like hashing a password before storing it).